# Automatic table show out of div(on inspect element) while in code it is already in div tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce, force.com

I am trying to add table in div on visual-force page but when i saved page and see in browser it is not appear on page and when trying to debug by inspect element it shows me out of div. here is the code.can you please advice here thank you.

```
<div id="tmp" align="center">
                    <font face="Arial"> <apex:pageBlock >
                            <apex:pageMessage severity="error" strength="0" rendered="false" />
                            <apex:pageMessages />
                        </apex:pageBlock>

                        <table align="center">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="loginPanel" rendered="{!(AND(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'), $Site.LoginEnabled))}">
                                <div id="content_wrap">
                                    <div id="form_wrap">
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <label for="j_id0:j_id1:j_id5:Username">Username:</label><apex:inputText value="{!username}" id="Username" required="true" size="40"/> 
                                                <label for="j_id0:j_id1:j_id5:Password">Password:</label><apex:inputSecret value="{!password}" id="Password" required="true" size="40"/>
                                                <apex:commandButton action="{!login}" value="Login"/>
                                            </fieldset>
                                            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.TimesheetSiteForgotPassword_v1}"> {!$Label.site.forgot_your_password_q}</apex:outputLink>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--form_wrap -->
                                    <div id="text_wrap" style="width:100px;height:100%;">
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- text_wrap -->
                                    <div>
                                        <table cellpadding="10">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center">
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="importantInfo">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Timesheet_Wireframe_Template_Login,'kforce-50.jpg')}" alt="Kforce 50th Anniversary" />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="importantInfo">
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
                                                                                    <b>Kforce Time Entry Supports The Following:</b>
                                                                                    <br />
                                                                                    <br />
                                                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                                        <tr>
                                                                                            <td align="center">
                                                                                                <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Timesheet_Wireframe_Template_Login, 'ico-firefox.gif')}" alt="FireFox 3.5" />FireFox 3.5
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                            <td align="center">
                                                                                                <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Timesheet_Wireframe_Template_Login, 'ico-safari.gif')}" alt="Safari 4" />Safari 4
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                            <td align="center">
                                                                                                <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Timesheet_Wireframe_Template_Login, 'ico-opera.gif')}" alt="Opera 10" />Opera 10
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                            <td align="center">
                                                                                                <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Timesheet_Wireframe_Template_Login, 'ico-chrome.gif')}" alt="Chrome" />Chrome
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                    </table>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td align="left">
                                                                                    <ul>
                                                                                        <li>
                                                                                            Use of the Time Entry and Time Entry Approval application in any browser not listed cannot be supported.
                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                        <li>
                                                                                            General Help is available by clicking the link at the top right corner.
                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                        <li>
                                                                                            If you cannot use web time entry for any reason, please contact the <b>Kforce Corporate Helpdesk at 1-866-807-5074</b>.
                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                        <li>
                                                                                            Please submit your timecard by close of business each Monday.
                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                        <li>
                                                                                            Training for&nbsp;<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LoginPageConsultantHelp" href="http://www.kforce.com/timeentry/help/KPAY_Training_Updated/KPAY_Consultant_TimeEntryv1.htm" target="_blank">Consultants</a>&nbsp;and&nbsp;<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LoginPageApproverHelp" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Approvers</a>
                                                                                        </li>

                                                                                    </ul>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                              </div>
                                    </div>
                                <!-- content_wrap -->

                            </apex:outputPanel>
                            <apex:outputPanel id="errorPanel" rendered="{!NOT(AND(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'), $Site.LoginEnabled))}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">Your last session was not correctly ended.
                                        Please be sure you log out when you finish. Please completely
                                        close your browser and relaunch.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </table>
                        <p />
                    </font>
                </div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: so you want text-wrap into form-wrap div?? show us how you are adding this?

Comment: Yes i wanna wrap whole table in div which is under "<!-- text_wrap -- >" this comment. it is already in div but on page it shows out of div.